# SPLUNK HOSTING ON DIFFERENT

Tags: azure-devops, splunk

How do we check the availability of each host on Splunk

Answer (score 1):

You should configure and user the Splunk distributed monitoring console, which will monitor the performance and availability of all Splunk instances and forwarders. I would also suggest you configure some alerts to be notified if anything goes wrong.

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/DMC/DMCoverview